# Creating data-frame with multiple variables in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 4 data-frames a,b,c,d with multiple variables in it (a=13, b=7, c=3, d=6). So, I want to create a new data-frame combining these.

What I did is, first using `library(tidyverse)`, I have united all variables in each data-frame with the names as below

```
Uni_a = gather(a, key, d) %>%
                 select(-key)
Uni_b = gather(b, key, d) %>% 
                 select(-key)
Uni_c = gather(c, key, d) %>% 
                 select(-key)
Uni_d = gather(d, key, d) %>%
                 select(-key)
```

Now, if I look at the dimensions

```
dim(Uni_a)
#[1] 819   1
dim(Uni_b)
#[1] 441   1
dim(Uni_c)
#[1] 189   1
dim(Uni_d)
#[1] 378   1
```

Now, here is the challenge: I want to create a final data-frame with Uni_a, Uni_b, Uni_c, Uni_d but unfortunately it return the error message-
dataframe=data.frame(Uni_a,Uni_b,Uni_c,Uni_d)

> Error in data.frame(Uni_a, Uni_b, Uni_c, Uni_d) : 
>   arguments imply differing number of rows: 189, 378, 819, 441.

Can anyone help me in this?

My objective is to create 4 variables in a data-frame for further analyse.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `cbind.fill` from `rowr`

```
library(rowr)
cbind.fill(Uni_a,Uni_b,Uni_c,Uni_d, fill = NA)
```

---

Instead of creating variables separately, it can be done in a loop with `map` by placing the objects in a `list`

```
library(tidyverse)
mget(letters[1:4]) %>%
    map(~ gather(.x, key, d) %>%
             select(-key)) %>%
    {do.call(cbind.fill, .)}
```

Comment: I tried this, it truly creates 4 variable, thank you @akrun, but the variable names are lost.$ d: int  5 5 0 5 5 5 4 0 4 4 ...
 $ d: int  5 3 4 3 5 4 5 3 4 4 ...
 $ d: int  1 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 ...
 $ d: int  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 4 ...

Comment: @sam Based on the example I created, it is not the case `cbind.fill(data.frame(col1 =1:5), data.frame(col2 = 1:7), data.frame(col3 = 1:9), fill = NA)`

Comment: What do you expect as output?  You should have provided a small reproducible example

Comment: Uni_a Uni_b Uni_c Uni_d
1 1 2 3
2 5 4 4
3 5 5 5
5 4 3 2

Comment: @sam Just set the names later i.e. `out <- cbind.fill(Uni_a,Uni_b,Uni_c,Uni_d, fill = NA); names(out) <- paste0("Uni_", letters[1:4])`